# Vimeo reporting unexpectedly high view counts

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

My company recently developed iOS and Android apps for an organization that uses Vimeo. The apps display video thumbnails and offer the ability for users to view the videos.

We did not use Web views in our apps, nor did we incorporate the Vimeo API. Instead, we play videos using the built-in system media players (such as AVPlayer on iOS). The URL we pass to the player looks like this:

http://player.vimeo.com/external/XXX.hd.mp4?s=XXX&profile_id=XXX&oauth2_token_id=XXXXX

The customer provided these URLs to us in their existing database. They also provided the URLs to thumbnail images, which we also use in the app. The thumbnail URLs look like this:

https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2FXXXX_1280x720.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png

This all works fine, but a few weeks after we launched the apps, the customer noticed that Vimeo is reporting much higher view counts for their videos than expected -- on the order of tens of thousands of views where it should be a few hundred (their apps require a subscription so they know how many users they have, and also they know from past activity on their web site that the numbers shouldn't be this high).

We aren't sure what is going on. The only thing we can think of is that we're somehow registering a view count every time we display a thumbnail image. Is this possible?

Could the media players be inadvertently making multiple requests to Vimeo each time we try to play a video?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Some media players do make multiple requests to the same video resource -- Vimeo may not be able to determine if multiple requests for a video file are originating from the same player or play session, so Vimeo's play stats for it may be inaccurate.

Vimeo Help Center article here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Direct-links-to-video-files